# How to get distribution name and version of OS in qmake

Tags: linux, windows, qt, debian, qmake

I want to get the distribution name and version name of OS in qmake. For Linux, in some distributions (Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS, ...), I used:

```
DISTRIBUTION = $$system(cat /etc/issue | cut -d\' \' -f1)
message($$DISTRIBUTION)
OSVERSION = $$system(cat /etc/issue | cut -d\' \' -f3)
message($$OSVERSION)
```

On my Debian 7.8, the output is:

```
Project MESSAGE: Debian
Project MESSAGE: 7
```

This is a correct result. But I'm not sure about this way.
I'm finding for Windows too: Windows 7, 8, ...

Do you have any idea about this in qmake?

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional assignments (see [Scopes and Contitions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#scopes-and-conditions)) ex.

```
win32:DISTRIBUTION = $$system(systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name")
unix:DISTRIBUTION = $$system(cat /etc/issue | cut -d\' \' -f1)
message($$DISTRIBUTION)
```

This way, the code will execute only on specific platforms. The command for Windows that I provided isn't the one you want, it prints the whole system name with version, you will have to modify it somehow.

Comment: Maybe I found an alternative to the expensive systeminfo call under windows on this site:
http://www.windows-commandline.com/find-windows-os-version-from-command/
This command produces an equivalent string for testing:
`wmic os get Caption,CSDVersion /value`